# Combine the rows of a pandas dataframe to a dictionary when a value is greater 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, sorting

I have reviewed this post. I have a dataframe with some entries. In column `A` are values at a certain `datetime`.

```
    date        A
0   2023-01-01  20
1   2023-01-02  30
2   2023-01-03  10
3   2023-01-04  0
4   2023-01-05  0
5   2023-01-06  0
6   2023-01-07  45
7   2023-01-08  20
8   2023-01-09  0
9   2023-01-10  0
10  2023-01-11  15
11  2023-01-12  0
```

I want to lookup for all entries in `A` where the `values != 0` and combine it to a block of appearence or variable of occurence. I want to output a `dict` where all successive values are combined even if there is only one entry by the `index` of the `dataframe`.

What I tried so far:

```
# identify in column where the value > 0
m = df['A'].gt(0)
```

This will give me `bool` so far so good:

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

To output all values in a dictionary:

```
# aggregate as list, convert the output to dictionary
pos = df[m].reset_index().groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum())['index'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output of `pos`:

```
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [6, 7, 10]}
```

But **expected** Output:

```
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [6, 7], 3: [10]}
```

Comment: could you add an example of your expected output?

Comment: Something like `df.groupby(df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift()).cumsum())['A'].agg(list)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to clarify this problem a little bit more, also with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output is unclear, but I imagine you might want to perform a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) as `list` with the consecutive 1 values, then convert [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
# identify 1s
m = df['B'].eq(1)

# group by successive values on the slice of 1 values
# aggregate as list, convert the output to dictionary
out = df[m].groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum())['A'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1: [20, 30, 10], 3: [45, 20, 2]}
```

##### updated question

```
m = df['A'].gt(0)

out = df.index[m].groupby(m.ne(m.shift())[m].cumsum())
```

Output:

```
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [6, 7], 3: [10]}
```

Comment: how can I find these identified blocks in that same `df`? For example to retrieve the value in an assumed new column `C` by the `index` of the first and last value in that `dict`.

Comment: can you provide the expected output as edit to your question?

Comment: Your **Output** is as expected. But how can I get the `index` or the position of these values in the `df`?
`{1: [20, 30, 10], 3: [45, 20, 2]}` for example get the `index` of the first value 20 and last value 10 in the first block and so on. With this index I want to get another value in another column.

Sorry for the misunderstandings!

Comment: Do you mean: `df[m].reset_index().groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum())['index'].agg(list).to_dict()`?

Comment: For first/last index: `df[m].reset_index().groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum())['index'].agg(['first', 'last'])`. If you edit your question with the clear expected output I might give you a better approach.

Comment: I edited the problem with the expected output. Hope it is more clear now.